# How do you decide who lives and who dies?

Tags: halacha, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

The Talmud [[Bava Metzia 62a]](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.62a.2?lang=bi) teaches as follows.  Two people are in a desert and only one of them has water.  If both drink, both will die, but if only one drinks, he will survive and reach civilization.  Ben Petora taught that both of them should drink and die. But Rabbi Akiva taught that the life  of the one who owns the water takes precedence.

This is fine when the decision about yourself is yours alone.  But what if it isn't?  How do third parties decide who lives and who dies if it's in their power to decide?

Example:  You are a doctor in the Intensive Care Unit and two patients, critically ill with coronavirus, and brought in.  You only have one ventilator.  Let's say they are the same age and equally likely to die.  How does halacha guide your decision on who lives and who dies?

Comment: The question is appropriately not framed about worth of life. Judaism isn't consequentialist utilitarianism. All life is valuable and we still need triage order to function. If the answer is a kohein comes first, it's not because he's more valuable but because someone has to go first.

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/950657/rabbi-hershel-schachter/piskei-corona-15-determining-whos-life-to-save-first/

Comment: VTC as too broad. Let me introduce you to most of Seder Nezikin. Without specific parameters regarding the two individuals’ situations, there’s no way to answer this question appropriately.

Comment: @DonielF -- What else do you need to know?  That was my question.  What are the criteria?